# Produce 1 month of current date and +1 month of current date

Tags: date, crystal-reports

My formula needs to calculated values for 1 month of current date and/or +1 month of current date. I know the following formula returns values up to one month before the current date:

DateAdd ("m", -1, CurrentDate)

But now I need to make the `-1` dynamic. Something along the lines of `DateAdd ("m", {?Custom_From_Date}, CurrentDate)`

The custom parameter will have numbers for months to be chosen. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: yes this is possible.. and I see your in right path and what you have done is correct... create a number parameter and write the same formula as you have written in question.... it will work

Comment: @Siva thanks for your response! But could you please elaborate your answer abit more (iam a crystal rookie)

Do you mean create a formula with DateAdd ("m", {?Custom_From_Date}, CurrentDate)

If so where does the formula go?

Comment: yes `DateAdd ("m", {?Custom_From_Date}, CurrentDate)` this is correct and to be more specific if you are looking for date output then use like this `CDate(DateAdd ("m", {?Custom_From_Date}, CurrentDate))`..Now coming to the usage.. what exactly you are trying to do with this formula like fetch the records or it is just display purpose?

Comment: Right, thanks @Siva thats cleared up a few things.
I want the end user to be able to choose record months before and after the current date The parameters to be displayed on SAP will have options to choose either 1,2,3 etc month proir and after the current date.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then in this case you need to use this formula in `record selection formula` like below.

First you need create a format like on you mentioned `{?Custom_From_Date}` and should ask user that enter a value with `-` if before current date and with `+` if after current date.

If your database date format is date then use like below in record selection formula

```
Database.datefield >=CDate(DateAdd ("m", {?Custom_From_Date}, CurrentDate))
```

if your database date format is datetime then use like below in record selection formula:

```
Database.datefield >=DateAdd ("m", {?Custom_From_Date}, CurrentDate)
```